# Latex code for three-phase inverter

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to use tikz to do something like this
[image: Three phase inverter]

but I have failed so far. I was looking around and I could not find a simple code for 3-phase inverters in tikz. Has someone a code to share?
Best

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: Circuitikz adds a lot of extra components, but is otherwise the same as TikZ.  The main difference is that TikZ components get bigger if you attempt to put text inside them.

Comment: @mario, look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/power-electronics-converter-inverter/ as a start. There are many examples to guide you there.

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, you could try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[americanvoltages,fulldiodes]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}\footnotesize

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0)  node[circ,label={180:o}]{}
              to[battery1={$\frac{V_{dc}}{2}$}] (0,2)
              to (6,2)  node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{c1}$}](S3){};
 \draw (S3.E) to (6,0)  node[circ,label={180:$V_{C}$}](vc){}
              to (6,-.5) node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{c2}$}](s3){};
 \draw (s3.E) to ++(-6,0) to[battery1={$\frac{V_{dc}}{2}$}] (0,0);
 \draw (S3.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S_3$}}]{};
 \draw (s3.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S^*_3$}}]{};

 \draw (2,2)  node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{a1}$}](S1){};
 \draw (S1.E) to (2,0)  node[circ,label={180:$V_{A}$}](va){}
              to (2,-.5) node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{a2}$}](s1){};
 \draw (S1.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S_1$}}]{};
 \draw (s1.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S^*_1$}}]{};

 \draw (4,2)  node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{b1}$}](S2){};
 \draw (S2.E) to (4,0)  node[circ,label={180:$V_{B}$}](vb){}
              to (4,-.5) node[Lnigbt,bodydiode,anchor=D,label={[label distance=10]100:$D_{b2}$}](s2){};
 \draw (S2.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S_2$}}]{};
 \draw (s2.B) node[circ,label={90:{$S^*_2$}}]{};

 \draw (va) to ++(.75,0) to ++(0,-2.5) node[ocirc,fill=none,label={180:$\nu_{an}$}](van){};
 \draw (vb) to ++(.75,0) to ++(0,-2.5) node[ocirc,label={180:$\nu_{bn}$}](vbn){};
 \draw (vc) to ++(.75,0) to ++(0,-2.5) node[ocirc,label={180:$\nu_{cn}$}](vcn){};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]